Can X become dhimmis?
How can we know whether the followers of a certain religion can become Dhimmis?
For example: In the hypothetical case that any neo-Pagan movement ever becomes large enough in a Muslim country or that a country that already has a large neo-Pagan community (like in Europe) ever becomes Muslim majority could they attain the same status as Zoroastrians and other non-People of the Book attained?
And would it make any difference if the movement itself claims to be monotheistic or henotheistic rather than outright polytheistic?

There is disagreement among the jurists on which disbelievers can become Dhimmis. The major stances are:

The stance of the Shafi'is and Hanbalis is that only the People of the Book (Jews and Christians) and Zoroastrians can become Dhimmis. No one else can become Dhimmis.

The stance of the Hanafis is that anyone other than apostates and Arab idolaters can become Dhimmis.

The stance of the Malikis is that anyone other than apostates can become Dhimmis.


By considering the above rules you can easily figure out yourself whether the followers of a religion can become Dhimmis or not under each madhab.
Ref: Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah: 7/122 , 15/173
